# Pandora-like playlist creation of local library

Tags: audio, music, media-player, collection-manager, music-recognition

Sometimes I want to listen to a particular feel of music but my music library is very diverse so not all of it fits in the feel I want to listen to.

Right now I have to resort to going to particular artists that I know are in that style but then I can only hear songs from them - I'd like a more diverse playlist. I would use the "genre" tag to do this, but most of the songs in my library have a wrong/no/slightly different genre tag which causes it to be pretty ineffective in sorting.

So, I'd like some software to create a playlist like Pandora does based on a song, band, or genre for my local music library. It can be for Windows, Mac, or Linux, but I'd prefer Windows. Extra points for not requiring an internet connection, but acceptable with internet required.

Does anyone know of a software that does this well?

Comment: Alternatively I'd be interested in a software that helps add the proper genre given a track and artist name but that's a different question